# "ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template" - vs2013 web forms template

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-identity

I made a web forms project with Visual Studio 2013. I didn't change the authentication set-up.

When I look at my web.config file I see this sentence:

> ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the
>   following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn
>   about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template

When I look at this site, I still can't find a way to fill in my providers.

Can I just add this xml-input for each provider (for default, membership, role and defaulsession)

```
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
```

Or is the identity framework changed in visual studio 2013? (OWIN)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default in Visual Studio 2013 when creating a new project, it uses the new ASP.NET Identity.  This does not use Membership providers, or profile providers that you are used to.  So no, you can't just add that configuration data.

You can add them back if you want, but understand that these probably won't be supported going forward.   They'll still work, but no new development will go on.

If you choose to use the new Identity model, then you have to consider that the old membership profile system was designed to address the fact that the membership model was brittle, and not easily extended.  This is not the case with ASP.NET Identity, and you are able to extend your user classes to provide information that would otherwise go into a profile in the old membership provider system.

But, to make this work, you're going to have to learn more about ASP.NET Identity and how it works, as there's too much to cover in a post here.  You can start at the link you mentioned.  You can also find more information at http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/authentication-and-identity